# DefaultSecurityFilterChain skipping the specifc antmatchers

Tags: spring-security

While configuring `Httpsecurity` in server side, I have 4 endpoints and I configured them according to roles.
But somehow only some antmatchers are registered in the filters, while skipping the few.

[Spring Security console o/p](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o9pG6.png):

```
2019-07-25 12:10:41.546  INFO 1028 --- [           main] o.s.s.web.DefaultSecurityFilterChain     : Creating filter chain: Ant [pattern='/resources/**'], []
2019-07-25 12:11:18.323  INFO 1028 --- [           main] o.s.s.web.DefaultSecurityFilterChain     : Creating filter chain: OrRequestMatcher [requestMatchers=[Ant [pattern='/oauth/token'], Ant [pattern='/oauth/token_key'], Ant [pattern='/oauth/check_token']]], [org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter@31ab75a5, org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter@7a2ffb0b, org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter@1af78e37, org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter@3cd28235, org.springframework.security.web.authentication.www.BasicAuthenticationFilter@36f80ceb, org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter@43b74979, org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter@7c751692, org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter@17541204, org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter@7d95a717, org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter@37fd496a, org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor@5a5b394]
2019-07-25 12:11:52.761  INFO 1028 --- [           main] o.s.s.web.DefaultSecurityFilterChain     : Creating filter chain: OrRequestMatcher [requestMatchers=[Ant [pattern='/user/getEmployeesList/**']]], [org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter@3777fc44, org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter@6bb71265, org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter@6d6d81c, org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter@35b79b1f, org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.authentication.OAuth2AuthenticationProcessingFilter@7668f8fd, org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter@37816ea6, org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter@7a74672, org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter@79454d8e, org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter@7c59cf66, org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter@67376bae, org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor@7eb94590]
2019-07-25 12:12:46.473  INFO 1028 --- [           main] o.s.s.web.DefaultSecurityFilterChain     : Creating filter chain: any request, [org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter@4ed5492c, org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter@65f96d58, org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter@69ae7632, org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter@19656e21, org.springframework.security.web.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter@54eb2bf6, org.springframework.security.web.authentication.ui.DefaultLoginPageGeneratingFilter@37d8562f, org.springframework.security.web.authentication.ui.DefaultLogoutPageGeneratingFilter@6d01f2e5, org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter@48a61e38, org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter@52a3eef8, org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter@66e434e8, org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter@1bbfd42f, org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter@69988d42, org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor@6167a456]
```

```java
@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

    http.authorizeRequests()
        .antMatchers("/").permitAll()
        .antMatchers("/user/getOperatorList").hasAuthority("ROLE_OPERATOR")
        .antMatchers("/operator/getOperator").hasAuthority("ROLE_OPERATOR")
        .antMatchers("/user/getEmployeesList").hasAuthority("ROLE_ADMIN")
        .antMatchers("/admin/getEmployeesList").hasAuthority("ROLE_ADMIN")
        .anyRequest().authenticated()
        .and().formLogin()
        .permitAll().and().logout().permitAll();

    http.csrf().disable();
}
```

Comment: Does your application work as expected?

Comment: This line `Creating filter chain: any request` is your configuration.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed this.
I need to add antmatchers for paths provided above in resourceserverconfiguration.
This Fixed my Solution.

```
@EnableResourceServer
@Override
public void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

    http.requestMatchers()
    .antMatchers("/admin/getEmployeesList")
    .and()
    .authorizeRequests()
```

`.antMatchers("/admin/getEmployeesList").access("hasRole('ADMIN').and()
        .requestMatchers()
        .antMatchers("/user/getOperatorList","/user/coaches", "/user/players", "/user/schools")
        .and()
        .authorizeRequests()")`

```
    .antMatchers("/user/getOperatorList").access("hasRole('OPERATOR')") 
    .antMatchers("/user/coaches").access("hasRole('COACH')")
    .antMatchers("/user/players").access("hasRole('PLAYER')")
    .antMatchers("/user/schools").access("hasRole('SCHOOL')")
    .and()
    .authorizeRequests()
    .anyRequest()
    .access("#oauth2.hasScope('read')");
}
```